# Menu with top and bottom scrollbars

Tags: coldfusion, yui

I have a web-site that uses CFMENU, which is essentially yui.

The top of each page contains a fixed div, and the menu sits within this fixed div.  When scrolling is necessary on the main portion of the page, it scrolls under this fixed div.

When a menu drops down when a page is scrolled all the way to the top, the menus drop down fully.

When the page is scrolled to the bottom, the menus display top and bottom scroll bars and the menus only display half their contents.

When I inspect the menu in firebug, there are two empty divs with "topscrollbar" and "bottomscrollbar" classes that appear.

Is there any way to prevent this?

FYI - When the menu is removed from the fixed div portion of the screen, there are no problems at all with the menus.

Comment: What version of ColdFusion are you using?

Comment: I am using CF10.  I should mention, however, that I am using CF10 via a shared host, so I do not have access to the core of cold fusion on the server in order to fidget with the system.

Comment: Stop using `cfmenu` and any other ColdFusion UI elements. You will run into limitations that will cause you to rip out your hair.

Comment: That is what I was seriously considering.  Good thing I am already bald.